# Colocar dois ícones no mesmo parágrafo

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Tenho um parágrafo em minha view. Nesse parágrafo, eu tenho a indicação do meu celular e peguei o símbolo do bootstrap, assim:

```
<p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone (Brasil) : +55 11 99999-8888</p>
```

Gostaria que junto com o símbolo do telefone, tenha também o do WhatsApp, ou seja, que apareçam os dois. É possível?

Tentei colocar o do WhatsApp e quando renderizo fica só ele, se coloco o phone por último, aí aparece só o phone, ou seja, ele não acrescenta nenhum mais.

Como eu faria isso, se for possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

É só adicionar outra tag com as classes `fa` e `fa-whatsapp`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<p>
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> 
  Phone (Brasil) : +55 11 99999-8888
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

crie uma tag "span" onde deseja colocar o símbolo do whatsapp, adicione a tag "class" e bote o fa fa-whatsapp" (não me recordo se é assim mesmo o nome da classe que condiz com o ícone do whatsapp)